# Redis performance compared to sql server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

We are using Redis cache (Nservicekit-Redis client) to store master data related to store info, error codes, brand info..etc, each module contains 1k-5k records and all records of each module data (`List<Store>`) is serialized and store with a key name in redis eg.,Store_master.

After observing some lag between web request and response, We came to know that most of time between round trip is consumed to get data from redis. In order to know  performance of redis with sql server database we have developed a sample application which return total seconds consumed to get data from redis/database.

We have observed that getting data from database (sql-server 2012) is faster and slightly equal than getting data from redis. We have performed test with multiple redis client(service stack/stack exchange/Nservicekit-redis) and data types(string/list) and results are same.

Our stored procedures have simple select queries as all the business logic will be handled by application. Does our application need redis cache or not? What are the best practices to store data in redis which increases performance of redis?

[image: screenshot of same test application]